# how to connect to multiple databases in drupal in order to display the content in a table

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-modules

i am using drupal in order to create a website on my localhost machine.

i have a mysql database that i want to connect it  to the drupal website and display its data in a table.

this is what i did in settings.php file

```
//connect to external database
$databases['sitesdb']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'sitesdb',
  'username' => 'xxxxxxx',
  'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

and in the drupal i download the Views Database Connector (VDC) module in order to  connect to the external database.

but it did not work .

second method  i used views and created content types that are the fields table of the  external databases.

but i do not know how to continue to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

I was using migrate module and multiple DB configuration looked like:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'main_db',
      'username' => 'XXX',
      'password' => 'XXX',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),

  'legacy' =>
    array (
     'default' =>
       array (
         'database' => 'additional_db',
         'username' => 'XXX',
         'password' => 'XXX',
         'host' => 'XXX',
         'port' => '',
         'driver' => 'mysql',
         'prefix' => '',
       ),
     ),

);
```

Comment: and use db_set_active() to switch database in code https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7.x